# Error when parsing system headers with RecursiveASTVisitor

Tags: c++, clang++, libtooling

I am building a standalone tool with libtooling. I have a basic boilerplate code for a `FrontendAction`, `Consumer` and a `Visitor`. The visitor only visits `ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl` where I just save some information. Everything works fine, but if I `#include <string>` in the file I am parsing I got an error: `'stddef.h' file not found`.

I thought the compiler couldnt find some system headers but the input file I am parsing compiles without any errors with the clang++ command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very typical error for `libTooling`-based tools: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#id3

> Some header files (stddef.h, stdarg.h, and others) are shipped with Clang — these are called builtin includes. Clang searches for them in a directory relative to the location of the clang binary. If you moved the clang binary, you need to move the builtin headers, too.

If you use **CMake** you can add the following code to install Clang's headers:

```
set(CLANG_BUILTIN_HEADERS_DIR "${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIR}/clang")

install(
  DIRECTORY ${CLANG_BUILTIN_HEADERS_DIR}
  DESTINATION lib
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  )
```